# error tex capacity exceeded

Tags: errors, capacity

I am having a hard time understanding what is wrong with the code below. When I run it in tex, I get an error input limit exceeded. The exact error is pasted below:

[image]

I am using texmaker to run the code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article} %{scrartcl}

    \usepackage{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents*}{Bibliografy.bib}
    @misc{wikipedia1,
      title = "Scripting language",
      author = "Wikipedia",
      url = {http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language},
      year = 2014,
    }
    \end{filecontents*}

    \usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
    \usepackage{url}

    \begin{document}    
    \cite{wikipedia1}
    \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
    %\bibliography{Bibliografy}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Strange.  I was able to compile your MWE.  Even if I cut out the `\usepackage{filecontents}` and put in the `\bibliography`-command.  Could you please add some more info.  Is this MWE really throwing an error for you?  If so, please, include the error message as quote.

Comment: Please add the full log instead. This is a parsed log (by texmaker) and it does not always tell the whole picture. Btw have you tried deleting the generated bib file and aux file and the compiled again?

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalled miktex and suddenly things started working. Thank you for your assistance