# error tex capacity exceeded log files added

Tags: errors, memory

I am having a hard time figuring out where the problem is with my code/workflow. I previously posted this question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350494/error-tex-capacity-exceeded), but then the same problem came straight back. When I run it in tex, I get an error input limit exceeded. The exact log is pasted below:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (MiKTeX 2.9.6210 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.1.26)  26 JAN 2017 20:45
entering extended mode
**./master.tex
(master.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 75 language(s) loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size11.clo"
File: size11.clo 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\apacite\apacite.sty"
Package: apacite 2013/07/21 v6.03 APA citation
\c@BibCnt=\count87
\bibleftmargin=\skip43
\bibindent=\skip44
\bibparsep=\skip45
\bibitemsep=\skip46
\biblabelsep=\skip47
)
No file master.aux.
\openout1 = `master.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 5.
\c@maskedRefs=\count88
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\apacite\english.apc"
File: english.apc 2013/07/21 v6.03 apacite language file
LaTeX Info: Redefining \BPBI on input line 129.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \BHBI on input line 130.
)
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\AtBeginDocument #1->#1

l.5 \begin{document}

If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 641 strings out of 493333
 7639 string characters out of 3139188
 74825 words of memory out of 3000000
 4254 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 3940 words of font info for 15 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 5000i,0n,4998p,136b,36s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I previously posted this question and thought I solved it but am having the same problem again.

The latex code I am trying to execute is below:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{apacite}
\nocite{*}

\begin{document}


% title page. Edit as needed for future publications. 
\title{Research Proposal}
\author{Teererai Marange \\
Department of Computer Science \\
University of Auckland\\
\texttt{t.marange@auckland.ac.nz}}
\date{January 26, 2017}
\maketitle
% end title page. 


% abstract goes here
\newpage
\begin{abstract}
Abstract goes here 
\end{abstract}
\newpage


% table of contents 
\tableofcontents
\newpage


%begin introduction 
\section {Introduction}
Lorem Ipsum Doremifaso 

%\cite{Nedakeyword} use to cite 



%references our biliography. This must go whereever we use our bibtex references

\bibliography{references}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}


\end{document}
```

and the bib file that I am using to build the bibliography is below:

```
@misc{wikipedia1,
  title = "Scripting language",
  author = "Wikipedia",
  url = {http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language},
  year = 2014,
}
```

Comment: You should update your previous question instead of adding a new one.

Comment: So does this mean I need to change the previous answer ie. code and log file since this is a problem that I've encountered in different code.

Comment: `\nocite{*}` command should be in the `document` environment, right?

Comment: In general, for next time yes, edit an existing question, but as I've answered here, I've voted to close the previous one as duplicate of this now.

Comment: I filed a bug report to the maintainer of `apacite.sty`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You get the error with just

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{apacite}

\nocite{*}
\begin{document}



\end{document}
```

moving no cite avoids it

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{apacite}


\begin{document}
\nocite{*}




\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

With the standard setup, `\nocite{*}` before `\begin{document}` would raise an error. The `apacite` style modifies `\nocite` so as to make it usable also in the preamble (which is not unreasonable) but it uses the wrong test for it.

Indeed the code for `\nocite` tests whether `\document` has become equivalent to `\@onlypreamble`, which means the document has started, and in this case it does the normal job; otherwise it issues `\AtBeginDocument{\nocite{...}}` (the argument is the same as the one of `\nocite`. However, when the tokens for `\AtBeginDocument` are executed, `\document` hasn't yet become equivalent to `\@preamble`. Which means that `\nocite{*}` will do `\AtBeginDocument{\nocite{*}}`, which… Infinite loop, because at that moment `\AtBeginDocument` is define to simply deliver its argument.

A fix for the code can be to execute `\AtBeginDocument` only if `\AtBeginDocument` has not become equivalent to `\@firstofone`.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{wikipedia1,
  title = "Scripting language",
  author = "Wikipedia",
  url = {http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language},
  year = 2014,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\nocite}
  {\AtBeginDocument{\nocite{#1}}}
  {\ifx\AtBeginDocument\@firstofone\else\AtBeginDocument{\nocite{#1}}\fi}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

% title page. Edit as needed for future publications. 
\title{Research Proposal}
\author{Teererai Marange \\
Department of Computer Science \\
University of Auckland\\
\texttt{t.marange@auckland.ac.nz}}
\date{January 26, 2017}
\maketitle
% end title page. 

% abstract goes here
\newpage
\begin{abstract}
Abstract goes here 
\end{abstract}
\newpage


% table of contents 
\tableofcontents
\newpage


%begin introduction 
\section {Introduction}
Lorem Ipsum Doremifaso 

%\cite{Nedakeyword} use to cite 



%references our biliography. This must go whereever we use our bibtex references

\bibliography{\jobname}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}


\end{document}
```

Of course, it is simpler to move `\nocite{*}` after `\begin{document}`. However, this might be fixed in the code for `apacite`.

Note that this patch won't work if `multibbl` is loaded. For that it would be much more complex, because the redefinition of `\nocite` is done at begin document.

I filed a bug report to the maintainer of `apacite.sty`.